# not working update method in rest API framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to edit registered User profile by using UpdateModelMixin class. The forms to edit is existed but when we want to PUT the new information , the new one is not applied and the pervious info is displayed.

models.py:

```
  class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entry_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    student_no = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.user.first_name + self.user.last_name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

views.py:

```
    class ProfessorDetailAPIView(DestroyModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, RetrieveAPIView):
        queryset = Professor.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ProfessorDetailSerializers

        def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

        def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py:

```
    class ProfessorDetailSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        user = CustomUserSerializer()
        professor_no = SerializerMethodField()

        class Meta:
            model = Student
            fields = (
                'user',
                'professor_no',
            )

        def get_professor_no(self, obj):
            return str(obj.professor_no)
```

There is not any changes applied on information

Comment: please update your question with Student model.

Comment: You can check if you're form is actually sending a PUT or a PATCH when you save it, and adjust the method you're using accordingly. A PATCH should be used to send to partially update an already existing resource, while [a PUT is intended to send *all* the data to replace the existing resource entirely](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/#put)

Comment: you mean I should add @detail_route(methods=['put', 'patch']) before my view class? It doesn't work